# scatter get identity generating a new publickey instead of using the keypair in the identity

Tags: eosjs, scatter

I am trying to verify if account name belong to a publickey gotten in the client side with the browser.

Why does scatter getIdenity function returns the right identity with the right eos account but different public key.

Calling getaccountkey in server side with the right publickey return the accounts related to it but for the generated publickey from the scatter return empty.